# Plot Option in High Charts

Tags: highcharts, highcharts-ng, angular2-highcharts

I use "Column" type High chart to Show two different data sets in my application. 
Both data are marked in a same column chart as different series. But I need to set two various `plotOption{}` for the graphs.

Highcharts is throwing error if I set the property within the `Series[]`.

If I set the Property using `plotOptions{}`, the property is getting applied for both the column Charts.

eg:

```
 series: [
    {
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Data1',
      data: data1,
      color: "#31598a",
      index: 0,
      legendIndex: 0
    },
    {
      type: 'column',
      name: 'Data2',
      data: data2,
      color: "#7e95a5",
    }]
```

here, I want to use the property "**linkedTo: ':previous'**" only for the **'data2'** series..

```
 plotOptions: {
    column: {
      grouping: false,
      shadow: false,
      borderWidth: 0,
      pointPadding: 0.3,
      pointWidth:12
    }
```

Defining the property inside this `plotOptions` is applying it to both the column series..

Is there anyway to apply property only to one particular series??

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE], that would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: I don't see why the `linkedTo` isn't working in the serie. [Here a simple Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/oy7mt19s/)

Comment: @Core972 Yeah.. Even I saw many similar fiddle examples where properties are directly declared inside the Series.. But in my scenario, I couldn't declare any property inside. I'm being alerted to declare it in plotOptions.

Comment: @Shylesh, please provide an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define individual options for series directly and it should works.

To workaround, you can create a new type of series, which will differ only by the type name from the column series and use it in `plotOptions`:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.seriesType('column2', 'column');


H.chart('container', {
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            ...
        },
        column2: {
            ...
        }
    },

    series: [{
            type: 'column',
            ...
        },
        {
            type: 'column2',
            ...
        }
    ]
});
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/omz0u7gs/

Comment: This workaround looks promising.. But when I tried to implement Highcharts.seriesType, there shows a error 

"[ts] Property 'seriesType' does not exist on type 'Static'. "
What do I do ??

Comment: Hi Shylesh, Maybe you did not import Highcharts? Without looking into your code, it's hard to say anything.

Comment: Yeah.. There was a Issue with the Highcharts module import.. This work around Works now! 
Thanks Alot!